# Nested loop - analysis of one variable by subsetting on two others variables

Tags: r, vectorization, nested-loops

My question is twofold: 1. As seen below, I have attempted to do a nested loop to subset based on two variables, then perform a t.test, followed by populating a data frame with those results. As it stands, my code only iterates over one variable and not both. What am I missing that is not allowing this to work?

2. I understand that vectorization my be helpful here but I am not familiar with this and would appreciate some feedback as to how this may be implemented.

Background: I have been working on a minor problem for a bit, and I am stuck. I am trying to analyze some data by subsetting using two variables. If I just wanted to get it done, I would just subset into data frames based on the first variable, then continue my analysis using the new data frames and the second variable for further subsetting. Having some experience with loops, I thought I would attempt to use a nested loop to do this for me. I have been able to get my loop to work well for a single variable to subset with, and build out a separate date frame that I can then use for other purposes. However, when I try to use the second variable, it is not working. Right now, the loops only creates 4 unique subsets, whereas it should ideally produce twelve. I think there is something obvious I am missing, and I have tried searching this forum and several others, but to no avail.

Here is my code to start:

```
    set.seed(10)
graphdata1 <-data.frame("RC" = sample(1:500, 1000, replace = T), "Gl" = sample(letters[1:3], 1000, replace = T), "CS" = sample(1:4, 1000, replace = T))

responsesGl <- as.vector(levels(as.factor(graphdata1$Gl))) 
results <- data.frame("n"=0, "ameans"=0, "CIameanslower"=0, "CIameansupper"=0)
results$Gl<- NA
results$CS <-NA
responsesCS <- as.vector(levels(as.factor(graphdata1$CS))) 

for(j in 1:length(responsesGl)) {
  
  for(i in 1:length(responsesCS))  {
      results$Gl[j] <- responsesGl[j] #adds in the first subsetting variable to the dataframe
      y <- subset(graphdata1, Gl == responsesGl[j]) #creates a subsetted dataframe of the larger data to analyze

      results$CS[i] <- responsesCS[i] #adds in the second subsetting variable
      x <- subset(y, CS == responsesCS[i]) #further subsets data to obtain only data that is a based on first and second variables
      results$n[i] <-length(x$CS) #determines number of responses in this category
      ttest <- t.test(x$RC) #this and the next four lines all analyze the data, while amending the analysis to the results dataframe
      confidence_interval <- as.vector(unlist(ttest["conf.int"]))
      results$ameans[i] <- mean(x$RC, na.rm = TRUE)
      results$CIameanslower[i] <- confidence_interval[1]
      results$CIameansupper[i] <- confidence_interval[2]

    if (length(results$n) == length(responsesCS)*length(responsesGl)) { #adds a row if the results sheet is not as long as the product of the response vectors (12 in this case)
  rm(x)
      rm(y)} else {
    results[nrow(results)+1,] <- NA #adds a row
    rm(x)
    rm(y)
  }
  }
}
```

From my searching I think I understand that R is supposed to run the inner loop first to completion, then increment the outer loop. Since I wanted to first subset on the first variable of Gl, then analyze for each variable of CS, I thought including my relevant Gl lines in the inner loop would be prudent. Of course it doesn't work and only produces this data frame with 4 rows completed but 8 empty rows (for a total of 12):

```
  n   ameans CIameanslower CIameansupper   Gl   CS
1  95 247.7579      218.2211      277.2947    a    1
2  84 257.3929      224.1692      290.6165    b    2
3  88 257.7500      226.3831      289.1169    c    3
4  68 244.8971      206.5598      283.2343 <NA>    4
5  NA       NA            NA            NA <NA> <NA>
6  NA       NA            NA            NA <NA> <NA>
7  NA       NA            NA            NA <NA> <NA>
8  NA       NA            NA            NA <NA> <NA>
9  NA       NA            NA            NA <NA> <NA>
10 NA       NA            NA            NA <NA> <NA>
11 NA       NA            NA            NA <NA> <NA>
12 NA       NA            NA            NA <NA> <NA>
```

I realize that the inner loop is also incrementing on the first variable (Gl), and I am not getting what I would like.

I want this output where all 12 rows would be populated with the averages and CIs of each unique subset based on the total number of unique combinations to subset (the following table is an example and ideally would have numbers filled in for n, ameans, upper and lower CI as seen for the first 4 rows):

```
  n   ameans CIameanslower CIameansupper   Gl   CS
1  95 247.7579      218.2211      277.2947    a    1
2  84 257.3929      224.1692      290.6165    a    2
3  88 257.7500      226.3831      289.1169    a    3
4  68 244.8971      206.5598      283.2343    a    4
5  NA       NA            NA            NA    b    1
6  NA       NA            NA            NA    b    2
7  NA       NA            NA            NA    b    3
8  NA       NA            NA            NA    b    4
9  NA       NA            NA            NA    c    1
10 NA       NA            NA            NA    c    2
11 NA       NA            NA            NA    c    3
12 NA       NA            NA            NA    c    4
```

Just to reiterate my questions: 1. what am I missing that is not allowing this to work?
2. I understand that vectorization my be helpful here but I am not familiar with this and would appreciate some feedback as to how this may be implemented.

Thank you

Dustin

Comment: It would help if you post what the expected result would look like. It is hard to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have amended my last comment to make it more obvious that I was after the last output I showed. Sorry that I was not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Comments on your code

First, about your loop, it can't fill in the data frame because you're calling the wrong index. For example:

```
for(j in 1:3){
  for(i in 1:4){
    results[j] <- something[j]
  }
}
```

In that case, `j` will only loop between 1 and 3, rewriting the previous result at each occurrence of the inner loop (in other words, you will write 3 times something in `results[1]`, 3 times in `results[2]`, ...). What you want to do is along those lines:

```
for(j in 0:2){
  for(i in 0:3){
    results[j*3 + i + 1] <- something[j]
  }
}
```

so that when `i=j=0`, you write in `result[1]`, when `i=1,j=0`, you write in `results[2]`, ..., when `i=0,j=1` you write in `results[4]`, ..., when `i=3,j=2` you write in `results[12]`. This could be enough to make the loop do what you want.

In addition, there are two small things that are not best practice but shouldn't affect the results: I think all your `as.vector()` are not useful and have no effect, and adding rows to a data frame during a loop is not a great idea.

For the second one, the idea is that a data frame is usually stored in a consecutive range in memory (same for a vector or matrix). When you add a row, you need to append something to where the data frame is already stored, if there is no space the whole data frame will get copied, which is slow and inefficient. When using a `for` loop, you always want to initialize your results variables with the right length:

```
N <- 12 #the length you want
results <- data.frame(n = rep(NA, N),
                      ameans = rep(NA, N),
                      CIameanslower = rep(NA, N),
                      CIameansupper = rep(NA, N))
# or an easier equivalent way:
results <- matrix(NA, nrow=N, ncol=4)
results <- as.data.frame(results)
names(results) <- c("n", "ameans", "CIameanslower", "CIameansupper")
```

But in R, that is rarely a concern since we can usually vectorize the operations.

## How to vectorize

You can do everything with base R, but why not use the best tools available: here it'll be much easier with the tidyverse (in particular the package `dplyr`).

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Now we can transform the original data frame.

```
graphdata1 %>%
  group_by(Gl, CS) %>%
  summarize(mean_RC = mean(RC),
            sd_RC = sd(RC),
            n = n())
```

So we easily have the mean, sd, and number of observations; you could add any summary statistic here.
But you want to do a t test. If I understand correctly, you want a one-sample test, comparing the mean in your sample to 0. You could try simply adding it in summarize:

```
graphdata1 %>%
  group_by(Gl, CS) %>%
  summarize(mean_RC = mean(RC),
            sd_RC = sd(RC),
            n = n(),
            t_test = t.test(RC))
# Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `t_test`.
# x Input `t_test` must be a vector, not a `htest` object.
# i Input `t_test` is `t.test(RC)`.
# i The error occurred in group 1: Gl = "c", CS = "1".
```

It doesn't work. But look at the error message: the test worked, but you can't just put the result of a test in a data frame. A magic trick is to use a "list-column": one of the columns of our data frame will be a list, that can contain anything, even whole test results.

```
graphdata1 %>%
  group_by(Gl, CS) %>%
  summarize(mean_RC = mean(RC),
            sd_RC = sd(RC),
            n = n(),
            res = list(t.test(RC)),
            .groups="drop")
```

I also added `.groups="drop"` to avoid having a grouping afterwards that may affect subsequent operations.

All we're left to do is extract the values of interest from the test results that are stored. There is again a trick: we need to specify that we want to do the computations row by row and not column by column, with `rowwise()`.

```
graphdata1 %>%
  group_by(Gl, CS) %>%
  summarize(mean_RC = mean(RC),
            sd_RC = sd(RC),
            n = n(),
            res = list(t.test(RC)),
            .groups="drop") %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(lower.ci = res$conf.int[1],
         upper.ci = res$conf.int[2])
```

And we're done! We can use `select()` to remove the columns that are not interesting anymore and rename and order the ones to keep, and `arrange()` to sort the rows by 1 or more variables.

```
graphdata1 %>%
  group_by(Gl, CS) %>%
  summarize(mean_RC = mean(RC),
            sd_RC = sd(RC),
            n = n(),
            res = list(t.test(RC)),
            .groups="drop") %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(lower.ci = res$conf.int[1],
         upper.ci = res$conf.int[2]) %>%
  select(Gl, CS, mean_RC,
         conf_low = lower.ci, conf_high = upper.ci) %>%
  arrange(rev(Gl), CS)
#     Gl    CS    mean_RC conf_low conf_high
#    <fct> <fct>   <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1  a     1        213.     181.      245.
# 2  a     2        225.     190.      260.
# 3  a     3        257.     229.      285.
# 4  a     4        221.     184.      257.
# 5  b     1        242.     214.      270.
# 6  b     2        255.     222.      288.
# 7  b     3        225.     196.      255.
# 8  b     4        236.     207.      264.
# 9  c     1        248.     218.      277.
# 10 c     2        257.     224.      291.
# 11 c     3        258.     226.      289.
# 12 c     4        245.     207.      283.
```

Comment: Alex, what a fantastic and useful explanation. I needed this, it makes so much more sense. I saw the edit, thank you for taking your time. It is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @Alexlok for the help. After looking over the answer, I will be using vectorization, as it is so much more efficient. For the sake of completion, I thought I would post my new nested loop code based on the suggestions.
The improvements:

1. I called the correct indexes using: (j-1)*3+i+(j-1)
   I found I needed to add the "+(j-1)" term to the indexes to prevent the loop from
   writing over itself.
2. I got rid of the as.vectors and removed the add rows function from the loop structure.
3. I made the data frame outside the loop for best practice.

   ```
   set.seed(10)
    graphdata1 <-data.frame("RC" = sample(1:500, 1000, replace = T), "Gl" = sample(letters[1:3], 1000, replace = T), "CS" = sample(1:4, 1000, replace = T))
    #got rid of as.vector()
    responsesGl <- levels(factor(graphdata1$Gl)) 
    responsesCS <- levels(factor(graphdata1$CS)) 


    #Create the data frame outside the loop.
    N <- length(responsesCS)*length(responsesGl)
    results <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow=N, ncol=6))
    names(results) <- c("n", "ameans", "CIameanslower", "CIameansupper", "Gl", "CS")
    #The nested loop function.
    for(j in 1:length(responsesGl)) {
      for(i in 1:length(responsesCS))  {
          results$Gl[(j-1)*3+i+(j-1)] <- responsesGl[j] 
          y <- subset(graphdata1, Gl == responsesGl[j]) 

      results$CS[(j-1)*3+i+(j-1)] <- responsesCS[i] 
      x <- subset(y, CS == responsesCS[i]) 
      results$n[(j-1)*3+i+(j-1)] <-length(x$CS) 
      ttest <- t.test(x$RC) 
      confidence_interval <- as.vector(unlist(ttest["conf.int"]))
      results$ameans[(j-1)*3+i+(j-1)] <- mean(x$RC, na.rm = TRUE)
      results$CIameanslower[(j-1)*3+i+(j-1)] <- confidence_interval[1]
      results$CIameansupper[(j-1)*3+i+(j-1)] <- confidence_interval[2]
    rm(x)
    rm(y)
    }}
   ```

Here is the output:

```
    n   ameans CIameanslower CIameansupper Gl CS
1  89 212.8202      181.0133      244.6271  a  1
2  77 224.8961      190.0473      259.7449  a  2
3  95 256.9895      229.0892      284.8897  a  3
4  68 220.5147      183.9511      257.0783  a  4
5  90 242.1667      214.4563      269.8770  b  1
6  75 254.9467      221.7683      288.1250  b  2
7  90 225.4333      195.6203      255.2463  b  3
8  81 235.7037      207.3833      264.0241  b  4
9  95 247.7579      218.2211      277.2947  c  1
10 84 257.3929      224.1692      290.6165  c  2
11 88 257.7500      226.3831      289.1169  c  3
12 68 244.8971      206.5598      283.2343  c  4
```

Thanks again!